# How can I see what version of Linux I'm running?

Tags: linux, linux-distributions

What's the Linux command that outputs the OS version? Like Winver.exe on Windows.

Comment: What do you mean by "Linux version"? The kernel version? Your distribution name? (Also, did you notice the duplicate question? Should have been shown to you right after entering your question title…)

Comment: I googled, I googled the superuser.com domain, I searched on superuser.com, I asked the question and reviewed the suggested questions. I just tried again and it suggests this question (obviously) but not that one. I tried!! :)

Comment: Interesting :) Well I hope you did find your answer there.

Comment: To get the Red Hat version type:
cat /etc/redhat-release

To get the SuSE version:
cat /etc/SuSE-release

To get the Kernel version (and sometimes the distributer) type:
cat /proc/version

The boot loader sometimes has what you're looking for:
cat /etc/grub.conf